# Getting elements of a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file. Each column represents a parameter and contains few values (eg. 1, 2, 3, 5) repeated hundreds of times. 
I want to write a python program that reads each column and stocks its content in a dictionary {column_header: list_numbers} (without repeating the numbers).

I tried to adapt the [example given in the python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html):

```
def getlist(file):
    content = dict()
    with open(file, newline = '') as inp:
        my_reader = reader(inp, delimiter = ' ')
        for col in zip(*my_reader):
            l = []
            for k in col:
                if k not in l:
                    l.append(k)
                print(k)    # for debugging purposes
            content[col[0]] = l
```

I was expecting, by printing k, to see each element of the column. Instead, I get several columns at a time.

Any idea about what is wrong?

Comment: Is order important? Or would a set be sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are almost there. I'd use a `set` to detect repeated numbers (more efficient):

```
def getlist(file):
    content = {}
    with open(file, newline = '') as inp:
        my_reader = reader(inp, delimiter = ' ')
        for col in zip(*my_reader):
            content[col[0]] = l = []
            seen = set()
            for k in col[1:]:
                if k not in seen:
                    l.append(k)
                    seen.add(k)
    return content
```

Make sure you get your delimiter right; if the above doesn't work for you then `print()` may show you whole *rows* with the delimiters still in them, as strings.

Say, your file uses `,` as a delimiter instead, the output would look something like:

```
{'a,b,c,d': ['0,1,2,3', '1,2,3,4']}
```

while configuring the correct delimiter would give you:

```
{'d': ['3', '4'], 'c': ['2', '3'], 'b': ['1', '2'], 'a': ['0', '1']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the following python script work for you?

```
import csv
test_file = 'test.csv'
csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(test_file, 'rb'), delimiter=',')

for line in csv_file:
    print line['x']
```